# How to search keywords in Visual Studio like in Google? Can we trim the white spaces?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, search

When I try to search some keywords in VS 2010, it just provides me Match Case, Match whole word Search Up. There is also regular expression option as well but when I try to deal with that, it's being a nightmare.

For example :

Let's say I have a variable that I use it in most of my stored procedures as an input.

And I have defined it as :

```
create procedure myProc (@myInputVar NVARCHAR(5)) ....do something...
```

but in some of my stored procedures, I have defined them with tabs (maybe 3-4 tabs) I.E.

```
create procedure myProc2 (@myInputVar            NVARCHAR(5)) ..... do something ...
```

I want to replace myInputVar type from String to INT. When I search "@myInputVar NVARCHAR(5)" keyword with search (Ctrl+F), it doesn't find the another stored procedure. I tried all options above which I have as search options.

Since I have a lot of procs (some has 3 tabs between type and name of the inout variable, some has 2 tabs, some has just white space), its being frustrating.

For instance, when we search something on Google, it doesn't care how many spaces between each word. It just shows the related words.

Is there any way to do it? with regular expression or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regexp:

for search box:

```
(\@myInputVar[\s\t]+)NVARCHAR\(5\)
```

and for replace box:

```
$1INT
```